# getting documents from another collection problem can't solve

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i have these 2 collection with a users collection and i want to make a list of providers for one user

[image]

i tried this code but not give me results :(

```
Future<List<ServineraProvider>> getfavoritesForUser() async{
    List<ServineraProvider> providers = [];
    await providerSkillsCollection.where('providerID', isEqualTo: this.uid).get()
      .then((onValue){
        for(int i=0; i<onValue.docs.length; i++){
          var doc = onValue.docs[i].data() as Map<String,dynamic>;
          print(doc['skillID']);
          skillsCollection.doc(doc['skillID']).get()
            .then((doc){
              var data = doc.data() as Map<String,dynamic>;
              providers.add(ServineraProvider(
                providerID: data['providerID'],
                providerName: data['providerName'],
                providerEmail: data['providerEmail'],
                providerPhoneNumber: data['providerPhoneNumber'],
                providerPicture: data['providerPicture'],
                providerState: data['providerState'],
                providerStatus: data['providerStatus']
              )
              );
            });
        }
     });
    return providers;
  }
```

i know there is a mistake but can't solve

Comment: what are you getting now?

Comment: i printed providers length is resulting 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're combining `then` with `await`, which is almost never a good idea. In this case it results in returning the `providers` list *after* the `providerSkillsCollection` query has completed, but *before* any of the providers themselves have been loaded.

To solve the problem with just `await`:

```
Future<List<ServineraProvider>> getfavoritesForUser() async{
  List<ServineraProvider> providers = [];
  var onValue = await providerSkillsCollection.where('providerID', isEqualTo: this.uid).get()
  for(int i=0; i<onValue.docs.length; i++){
    var doc = onValue.docs[i].data() as Map<String,dynamic>;
    print(doc['skillID']);
    var doc = await skillsCollection.doc(doc['skillID']).get()
    var data = doc.data() as Map<String,dynamic>;
    providers.add(ServineraProvider(
      providerID: data['providerID'],
      providerName: data['providerName'],
      providerEmail: data['providerEmail'],
      providerPhoneNumber: data['providerPhoneNumber'],
      providerPicture: data['providerPicture'],
      providerState: data['providerState'],
      providerStatus: data['providerStatus']
    ));
  }
  return providers;
}
```

Comment: can i transform this code to stream and getting same result? if yes can u help

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish. Does the code in my answer return the array of providers? If so, why do you want to transform this code?

Comment: your code is very good but future doesn't work when there is no internet while stream saves data and I can see the data while no net

Comment: I doubt that behavior was introduced by the change to your code in my answer. More likely the same behavior was present in your original code, and my fix to that code inherits it - as your question was not about offline  behavior.  Does that make sense?